# AlertView open Safari

Tags: ios, xcode

i have made an alert:

```
UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"mymaths.co.uk" message:@"This is a great website for maths exercises!! Have fun!!\n\rIf you prefer to view the website in Safari just press \"Safari\"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: @"Safari",nil];
    [alert1 show];
```

As you can see, my second button is called "Safari", and it is delegated through this code:

```
-(void) alertView: (UIAlertView *)alert1: clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
```

}

But now if I click Ok (the cancel button) it opens safari, and if I click Safari, it opens safari as well.
if I write:

```
-(void) alertView: (UIAlertView *)otherButtonTitles Safari: clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
```

}

both buttons cancel.
How can I fix this? the aim is to press "OK" that cancels, and "Safari" to open safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the alert view delegates with button indexes in the below function that will do,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Safari");
    }
}
```

Comment: -(void) alertView: (UIAlertView *)alert1: clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"@Cancel");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Safari");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    }
}

Comment: Am sorry didn't realise that the delegate function signature was wrong! Check the result now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did for my project.

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error Title", nil) message:authMessage delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil) otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Captcha Required Button", nil), nil];
alert.tag = captchaalert;
```

I'm setting a tag attribute to the alert in case there are more than one that need to open Safari when you click them.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag == captchaalert){
        if(buttonIndex==1){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha"]];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry to tell you that none of the two worked. I found a working code, so problemsolved, but thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Well that's odd it's working fine on my app.. Anyway, you're welcome.